# SORM: Attempt to refer to an unpersisted entity

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.2, sorm

I'm using **playframework 2.2.1** with **scala 2.10** and **SORM 0.3.10** for mysql db.
When I'm trying to save instance of simple case class:

```
case class User(email: String, password: String, token: String, verified: Boolean = false, atoken: UserAuthToken) {
    def save = Db.save[User](this)
}
```

I'm gettin this error:

```
sorm.core.SormException: Attempt to refer to an unpersisted entity: UserAuthToken(7779235c1fd045f39ced7674a45baaa2,1387039847)
```

What I'm doing wrong? `UserAuthToken` is quite simple too:

```
case class UserAuthToken(token: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString.replace("-",""), expire: Int = (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis/1000).toInt + 60*60*365)
```

Both classes are registered as entities in Db object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserAuthToken` is an entity, meaning that it is mapped to some row in DB. For both you and SORM to be able to identify that row (and the entity), the `Db.save(..)` method returns a value of type `UserAuthToken with Persisted`, i.e. a copy of the original value with the identification information.

`User` is an entity too, but it refers to `UserAuthToken`, meaning that the row it is mapped to must store the identification info on `UserAuthToken`. So for you to be able to persist a value of type `User`, it must refer only to an already persisted `UserAuthToken`. I.e.:

```
..
val persistedUserAuthToken = Db.save(userAuthToken)
val persistedUser = Db.save( User(.., atoken = persistedUserAuthToken) )
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I thought about dat, but didnt pass persisted token as parameter, seems like it was a mistake :)